# How to include a selection hyperlink without a newline

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm using the QuestionForm schema for a mechanical turk survey. I'd like to include a link to a google search of each of the suggested answers in the form. So if `b` is a possible answer, I would like `b` to appear as a link to a google search of that word.

The problem is that when I use the `<FormattedContent>` tag, the answer is being put in a new block, preceded by a newline, and this makes the form unnecessarily long.

Any way to avoid that pesky newline?

Here's a snippet from the XML I'm using:

```
<AnswerSpecification>
  <SelectionAnswer>
    <MinSelectionCount>1</MinSelectionCount>
    <MaxSelectionCount>2</MaxSelectionCount>
    <StyleSuggestion>checkbox</StyleSuggestion>
    <Selections>
      <Selection>
        <SelectionIdentifier>a</SelectionIdentifier>
        <FormattedContent><![CDATA[<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=a">a</a>]]></FormattedContent>
      </Selection>
      <Selection>
        <SelectionIdentifier>b</SelectionIdentifier>
        <FormattedContent><![CDATA[<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=b">b</a>]]></FormattedContent>
      </Selection>
    </Selections>
  </SelectionAnswer>
</AnswerSpecification>
```